# Vite Proxy Using Http2 returns "unable to verify the first certificate"

Tags: reactjs, ssl, proxy, http2, vite

I am trying to setup a development environment using HTTP2 requests with Vite and a local backend. I proxy requests between client and server both running on localhost. The server is configured with a generated certificate using Mkcert (https://github.com/FiloSottile/mkcert).

**Configuration:**

To configure the certificate I run the following steps:

1. `mkcert.exe -pkcs12 "test" "127.0.0.1" "localhost"`
2. Configure the backend to use the generated cert
3. `mkcert.exe -install`
4. Use the following vite configuration:

```
server: {
  https: {
    pfx: fs.readFileSync(`./cert/test.pfx`),
    passphrase: "some-phrase",
  },
  proxy: {
    "/api": {
      target: `https://localhost:15000`,
      changeOrigin: true,
      secure: true,
    },
  },
},
```

Currently this configuration works on Mac but fails on Windows. Both use the same backend and certificates but on Windows the proxy will fail with: "unable to verify the first certificate". In the browser the certificate chain is a correctly validated.

**Troubleshooting:**

When I run `openssl s_client -showcerts -connect localhost:15000 -servername localhost` the query results in "unable to verify the first certificate" as well basically indicating that the mkcert Root CA isn't properly found.

Using `openssl s_client -showcerts -CAfile "C:\Users\SomeUser\AppData\Local\mkcert\rootCA.pem" -connect localhost:15000 -servername localhost` the certificates will be correctly validated. This should indicate that the proxy lacks a reference to the `rootCA` of Mkcert.

I have tried supplying the rootCA using the following script in `package.json`:

`"dev": "cross-env NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=\"C:\\Users\\SomeUser\\AppData\\Local\\mkcert\\rootCA.pem\" && vite",`

This doesn't help however and the proxy still fails with the same error. I assume Mac and Windows work differently when supplying the CA root certs to Node or fails silently?

Anyway, how can this solved? I have been thinking about supplying the full cert chain in a cert that I supply to Vite, but this shouldn't be needed if Node could just reference the RootCA correctly.

Answer (score 0):

you need to configure ca for **target** like that:

```
https: true,
proxy: {
  '/api': {
    secure:false,
    changeOrigin: true,
    //TARGET
      target: {
        protocol:'https:',
        host:'videotest.lgh',
        port: 443,
        ca:  readFileSync('./src/key/CA.pem'),
      },
      rewrite: (path) => path.replace(/^\/api/, ''),
  }
}
```

Seems vite will not use Windows's rootCA cert store, so we need to configure it by ourselves.